# Can `dotnet fsi` be run in .NET Framework mode?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, dotnet-cli

I'd like to reference some .NET Framework-only packages from an F# script, and run it using:

```
dotnet fsi script.fsx
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
warning NU1701: Package 'Hymans.ESF.Api 1.9.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net5.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

Is there a way to use `dotnet fsi` with .NET Framework packages?

Answer (score 4):

If you have Visual Studio installed, you can run the .NET Framework version of F# Interactive by executing `fsi.exe` from a developer command prompt.

Comment: and what's the location of that file? I ask because it seems to keep changing all the time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67800998/githubactions-ci-windows-vms-dont-have-fsi-exe-anymore-or-it-changed-location

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\Tools

Comment: For Visual Studio 2022, the path is (make sure to correct the edition of Visual Studio you are using): 

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community|Professional|Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\Tools\fsi.exe